# Cursor in SQL Server taking too much time for 35 million records

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, database-cursor

I have created a cursor in a stored procedure, my select statement result has around 35 million records.

I am fetching each value of cursor and executing the stored procedure, in turn the next stored procedure is calling another stored procedure which has a few insert statements.

The query is taking more than 2 days to complete its execution, each time a cursor row takes 0.7 second, and there are 35 million rows.

The query is as below:

```
-- Created a cursor to read over data
DECLARE testCursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD LOCAL FOR
    SELECT 
        StartTime, EndTime, [datares], Id, address,
        c.RCount, c.SCount 
    FROM 
        ConData c

-- Opening the cursor and fetching the first Condata
OPEN testCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM testCursor INTO
    @startTime, @endTime, @datares, @Id, @address, @rCount, @sCount

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    EXEC InsertOrUpdateConData @startTime, @endTime, @datares, @Id, @address, @rCount, @sCount

    UPDATE DataRec
    SET EndTime = @endTime
    WHERE Id = @pId AND Type = 'ConData' AND Int1 = @Id

    -- Fetch the next conversation
    FETCH NEXT FROM testCursor INTO
        @startTime, @endTime, @datares, @Id, @address, @rCount, @sCount
END

CLOSE testCursor 
DEALLOCATE testCursor
```

How can I reduce the amount of time required for this query to execute?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Is a cursor really needed?

Comment: I need to insert data what ever i selected from select statement to few tables by calling a sp and merge data also. So what is the best possible solution instead of cursors, because cursor is taking more than 2 days

Comment: You're surprised that tool designed to work with datasets is taking a long time to process 35 millions rows 1 agonising row at a time; something it is specifically not designed to do? You need to change from thinking rows and start thinking in datasets when working with a DBMS.

Comment: What is your SP actually doing? Can you post the DDL? Perhaps the SP could be changed to accept a table value parameter, or perhaps you could simply perform the operation outside of an SP.

Comment: what if you split your dataset and run several queries at the same time. for example a cursor for id > 17500000 and a cursor for id <= 17500000 ..

Comment: and it can be extended to more queries..i think it might help

Comment: We can't make specific suggestions unless you post the `InsertOrUpdateConData` proc code but the name suggests you might be able to use a set-base `MERGE` statement for this task.

Comment: @Larnu My sp has again 3 insert statements, where am inserting the data based on if id doesnt exists already in a another table then I will insert data in other 3 tables

Comment: @DanGuzman InsertOrUpdateConData  where am inserting data into 3 tables based on a condition. So need to know instead of processing each row and calling sp what else can be done ?